# React js, embed javascript widget

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im trying to embed this javascript code to a react js component, any help or guide I can read will help. I have tried de Helmet library , but not possible, this widget connects to a hotel booking system and this is the code they give me.

```
<!-- 
    WuBook Javascript Library
    Eventually, put it inside
    your <head/> tag
-->
<script src="https://wubook.net/js/wblib.jgz"></script>
<!-- 
     put the following div where WuBook 
     should be designed. Make sure to
     preserve the div contents (backlink)
-->
<div id="_baror_" >
  <a href="https://es.wubook.nethttps://wubook.net/page/WooDoo-Booking-Engine-35.html" style="display: block; margin-top: 5px; text-decoration:none;border:none;" target="_blank">
    <img src="https://wubook.net/imgs/default/booking_by_wu.gif" alt="Booking Engine Wubook" title="Soluciones de gestión hotelera" style="border:none;text-decoration:none;" />
  </a>
</div>
<!-- 
     Initialize the WuBook Object.
     Collect params settings.
     Call WuBook.design_bwidget().

     Notice WuBook Object provides a
     lot of interesting features.
-->
<script>
  var WuBook= new _WuBook(xxxxxxx);
  var wbparams= {
    textcolorpk: '#313131',
    fixedPosition: 0,
    ditextcolor: '#ffffff',
    textcolorbb: '#ffffff',
    plusperc: 0,
    listtypebb: '#ffffff',
    buttoncoloras: '#f7422b',
    iconcoloras: '#ffffff',
    rpkgs: '',
    avgcolor: '#ffffff',
    labelcoloras: '#ffffff',
    barbackground: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
    default_nights: 1,
    textcolorcalendarbe: '#422715',
    bordercolor: '#ffffff',
    blocks: 'be',
    failback_lang: 'en',
    hdcode: '',
    textcolorbuttonbe: '#ffffff',
    avgtextcolor: '#ffffff',
    diinputcolor: '#ffffff',
    lang: '',
    buttoncolorbe: '#c88139',
    dibuttoncolor: '#008000',
    wbgoogle: 1,
    bgblocks: '#000000',
    cmsgs: '',
    textcolornightspk: '#ffffff',
    adchi: 1
  };
  WuBook.design_bwidget("_baror_", wbparams);
</script>
```

I'm kind of new to react js, but i have background on JS , HTML and CSS